# Scheme function for time signatures in LilyPond

Tags: notation, lilypond, time-signatures, lily-scheme

I would like to notate a piece proportionally in LilyPond in which different time signatures are layered polymetrically. To do this, I want to place the time signatures above the staves, or more precisely: above the bar lines. And I want to do this with a markup, because the space that the time signatures occupy before the first note (or rest) of a bar naturally remains if I simply move them vertically and horizontally with a \override command (e.g. with \override TimeSignature.extra-offset = #'(-2 . 8)). In short: the first note (or rest) of a bar is always set a little too far to the right than it should be according to a precise proportional notation.

So what I want to do is write a function in which I can insert the time signatures into the notes with a markup command. I'm thinking of something like this:

```
\version "2.25.2"

\relative c' {
  \override Score.TimeSignature. stencil = ##f 
   c4 d e f

 \mark \markup {
    \override #'(baseline-skip . 1.5)
    \override #'(font-size . 4.5)
    \override #'(font-name . "Bodoni72 Book")
    \override #'(whiteout-style . outline)
    \override #'(whiteout . 1)
    \override #'(extra-offset . -2)
    \column {
      \raise #0.5 \scale #'(0.8 . 0.8) "4" % Numerator of the time signature
      \raise #-0.5 \scale #'(0.8 . 0.8) "8" % Denominator of the time signature
    }
  }
  c8 d e f
}
```

It should be possible to pass numerators and denominators as arguments to such a function.

I am currently learning Scheme, but my knowledge is not yet sufficient to write such a function. Maybe someone can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first: Such a function does exist (at least, a more powerful such function does exist):

```
\markup\compound-meter #'(4 8)
```

But if you really wanted to do your own function you’d need to define either a *markup command* (drawing the actual markup) or a *scheme function* (returning a markup to be drawn later). The markup command will be resolved later, which allows it to consider properties passed along. Of course you could also do a *music function* returning the actual mark event. See here how this would be done:

```
tsMarkup =
#(define-scheme-function (num den) (number? number?)
   #{
     \markup {
      \override #'(baseline-skip . 1.5)
      \override #'(font-size . 4.5)
      \override #'(font-name . "Bodoni72 Book")
      \override #'(whiteout-style . outline)
      \override #'(whiteout . 1)
      \override #'(extra-offset . -2)
      \column {
        \raise #0.5 \scale #'(0.8 . 0.8) #(number->string num) % Numerator of the time signature
        \raise #-0.5 \scale #'(0.8 . 0.8) #(number->string den) % Denominator of the time signature
      }
     }
   #})

#(define-markup-command (timesig layout props num den) (number? number?)
   (interpret-markup
    layout props
    #{
      \markup {
       \override #'(baseline-skip . 1.5)
       \override #'(font-size . 4.5)
       \override #'(font-name . "Bodoni72 Book")
       \override #'(whiteout-style . outline)
       \override #'(whiteout . 1)
       \override #'(extra-offset . -2)
       \column {
         \raise #0.5 \scale #'(0.8 . 0.8) #(number->string num) % Numerator of the time signature
         \raise #-0.5 \scale #'(0.8 . 0.8) #(number->string den) % Denominator of the time signature
       }
      }
    #}))

tsMark =
#(define-music-function (num den) (number? number?)
   #{
     \mark\markup {
      \override #'(baseline-skip . 1.5)
      \override #'(font-size . 4.5)
      \override #'(font-name . "Bodoni72 Book")
      \override #'(whiteout-style . outline)
      \override #'(whiteout . 1)
      \override #'(extra-offset . -2)
      \column {
        \raise #0.5 \scale #'(0.8 . 0.8) #(number->string num) % Numerator of the time signature
        \raise #-0.5 \scale #'(0.8 . 0.8) #(number->string den) % Denominator of the time signature
      }
     }
   #})

\relative c' {
  \override Score.TimeSignature. stencil = ##f 
  c4 d e f

  \time 4/8
  \mark\markup\compound-meter #'(4 8)
  c8 d e f
  \mark\markup\timesig #4 #8
  c8 d e f
  \mark \tsMarkup 4 8
  c8 d e f
  \tsMark 4 8
  c8 d e f
}
```

Generally instead of manually creating these marks it would be fairly simple though to include a custom Time signature engraver creating these marks for you (this might be a good example to understand how engravers work):

```
#(define (Top_time_signature_engraver context)
   (let* ((cause '()) (last-fraction #f))
     (make-engraver
      (listeners
       ((time-signature-event engraver event)
        (set! cause event)))
      ((process-music engraver)
       (let ((frac (ly:context-property context 'timeSignatureFraction)))
         (if (not (equal? frac last-fraction))
             (let ((grob (ly:engraver-make-grob engraver 'RehearsalMark cause)))
              (ly:grob-set-property! grob
                                     'text
                                     #{
                                       \markup {
                                        \override #'(baseline-skip . 1.5)
                                        \override #'(font-size . 4.5)
                                        \override #'(font-name . "Bodoni72 Book")
                                        \override #'(whiteout-style . outline)
                                        \override #'(whiteout . 1)
                                        \override #'(extra-offset . -2)
                                        \column {
                                          \raise #0.5 \scale #'(0.8 . 0.8) #(number->string (car frac)) % Numerator of the time signature
                                          \raise #-0.5 \scale #'(0.8 . 0.8) #(number->string (cdr frac)) % Denominator of the time signature
                                        }
                                       }
                                 #})))
         (set! last-fraction frac)
         (set! cause '()))))))

\layout {
  \context {
    \Staff
    \remove Time_signature_engraver
    \consists #Top_time_signature_engraver
  }
}

{ 4 4 4 4 \time 5/4 4 4 4 4 4 }
```

In simple words this engraver will always create a mark as soon as the time signature fraction changes. If a `\time ...` event exists it is provided as *cause*, which allows for things such as point and click.

This also allows you to specify the marks at whatever level you might want — Staff level:

```
\layout {
  \context {
    \Staff
    \remove Time_signature_engraver
    \consists #Top_time_signature_engraver
  }
}

<<
  \new StaffGroup <<
    \new Staff { 4 4 4 4 \time 5/4 4 4 4 4 4 }
    \new Staff { 4 4 4 4 \time 5/4 4 4 4 4 4 }
  >>
  \new StaffGroup <<
    \new Staff { 4 4 4 4 \time 5/4 4 4 4 4 4 }
    \new Staff { 4 4 4 4 \time 5/4 4 4 4 4 4 }
  >>
>>
```

Score level:

```
\layout {
  \context {
    \Staff
    \remove Time_signature_engraver
  }
  \context {
    \Score
    \consists #Top_time_signature_engraver
  }
}

<<
  \new StaffGroup <<
    \new Staff { 4 4 4 4 \time 5/4 4 4 4 4 4 \time 7/8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 }
    \new Staff { 4 4 4 4 \time 5/4 4 4 4 4 4 \time 7/8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8}
  >>
  \new StaffGroup <<
    \new Staff { 4 4 4 4 \time 5/4 4 4 4 4 4 \time 7/8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8}
    \new Staff { 4 4 4 4 \time 5/4 4 4 4 4 4 \time 7/8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8}
  >>
>>
```

Staff group level:

```
\layout {
  \context {
    \Staff
    \remove Time_signature_engraver
  }
  \context {
    \StaffGroup
    \consists #Top_time_signature_engraver
  }
}

<<
  \new StaffGroup <<
    \new Staff { 4 4 4 4 \time 5/4 4 4 4 4 4 \time 7/8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 }
    \new Staff { 4 4 4 4 \time 5/4 4 4 4 4 4 \time 7/8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8}
  >>
  \new StaffGroup <<
    \new Staff { 4 4 4 4 \time 5/4 4 4 4 4 4 \time 7/8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8}
    \new Staff { 4 4 4 4 \time 5/4 4 4 4 4 4 \time 7/8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8}
  >>
>>
```